# How to print backslash with ImageMagick convert caption feature?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, caption

I'm trying to print pretty simple stuff

```
The double quotes "
The single quote '
The backslash \
And 2x backslashes \\
```

I'm using this command

```
convert -size 600x600 -gravity center -pointsize 30 caption:"The double quotes \"\nThe single quote \'\nThe backslash \\ \nAnd 2x backslashes \\\\" out.jpg
```

And getting this result:

[image: Image output]

**The problem is that escaping backslashes is not working correctly**

I've tried to run the command with *single quotes* instead of double likes this:

```
convert -size 600x600 -gravity center -pointsize 30 caption:'The double quot...
```

But then I do not know how to escape single quote `'`. I do know that is trivial but I do not have any other ideas.

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37751.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you seek like this:

```
convert -size 600x600 -gravity center -pointsize 30 caption:'The double quotes \"\nThe single quote '"'"'\nThe backslash \\ \nAnd 2x backslashes \\\\' out.jpg
```

[image]